# Android GC concerns

Tags: android, react-native, mapbox, mapbox-android

Im on the newer side to Android development and my app is experiencing some severe lag on the main thread.  Would these GC calls have anything to do with it? or is this a normal thing to see.

````
I/tific.driverap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 436286(11MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 32% free, 12MB/18MB, paused 2.970ms total 230.965ms
I/tific.driverap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 224993(6870KB) AllocSpace objects, 19(1380KB) LOS objects, 28% free, 15MB/21MB, paused 736us total 258.562ms
I/tific.driverap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 440643(11MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 29% free, 14MB/20MB, paused 420us total 233.459ms
I/tific.driverap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 409285(10MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 29% free, 14MB/20MB, paused 440us total 215.443ms
I/tific.driverap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 411403(10MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 29% free, 14MB/20MB, paused 525us total 223.011ms
I/tific.driverap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 397975(10MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 30% free, 13MB/19MB, paused 341us total 196.789ms
I/tific.driverap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 379872(9998KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 30% free, 13MB/19MB, paused 299us total 224.557ms
I/tific.driverap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 382321(10080KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 29% free, 14MB/20MB, paused 466us total 252.027ms
I/tific.driverap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 411782(10MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 28% free, 15MB/21MB, paused 1.189ms total 311.090ms
I/tific.driverap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 429426(11MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 28% free, 14MB/20MB, paused 438us total 258.491ms
I/tific.driverap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 412358(10MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 29% free, 14MB/20MB, paused 384us total 233.106ms
I/tific.driverap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 412384(10MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 32% free, 12MB/18MB, paused 1.093ms total 232.966ms
I/tific.driverap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 221802(6845KB) AllocSpace objects, 19(1396KB) LOS objects, 28% free, 14MB/20MB, paused 430us total 229.454ms
I/tific.driverap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 420315(10MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 30% free, 13MB/19MB, paused 374us total 225.603ms
I/tific.driverap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 378988(10068KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 31% free, 13MB/19MB, paused 2.494ms total 198.410ms
I/tific.driverap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 356831(9401KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 30% free, 13MB/19MB, paused 385us total 215.738ms
I/tific.driverap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 382030(10081KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 29% free, 14MB/20MB, paused 399us total 231.409ms
I/tific.driverap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 399387(10MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 29% free, 14MB/20MB, paused 582us total 228.174ms
I/tific.driverap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 391696(10MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 29% free, 14MB/20MB, paused 359us total 218.308ms
I/tific.driverap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 399123(10MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 28% free, 14MB/20MB, paused 529us total 247.203ms
I/tific.driverap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 420398(10MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 30% free, 13MB/19MB, paused 509us total 200.576ms
I/tific.driverap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 366451(9790KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 30% free, 13MB/19MB, paused 409us total 184.785ms
I/tific.driverap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 363281(9546KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 30% free, 13MB/19MB, paused 525us total 230.178ms
I/tific.driverap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 280810(8350KB) AllocSpace objects, 19(1408KB) LOS objects, 29% free, 14MB/20MB, paused 347us total 231.230ms
I/tific.driverap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 391712(10MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 29% free, 14MB/20MB, paused 353us total 220.790ms
I/tific.driverap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 396997(10MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 29% free, 14MB/20MB, paused 505us total 240.837ms
I/tific.driverap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 403403(10MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 29% free, 14MB/20MB, paused 805us total 228.186ms
I/tific.driverap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 389127(10MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 29% free, 14MB/20MB, paused 529us total 223.680ms```
````

Comment: Have you tried profiling your app’s memory footprint? I believe you can figure out what’s overloading the heap (and therefore overloading the GC). See https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory#monitor

Comment: I havent, Ill take a look thanks.  So this does look like its being overloaded?

Comment: Logically thinking, lots of memory allocation will cause a lot of memory releases (or else your heap will explode). Do you have a custom view which override `onDraw`?